# Generate Signed APK на другом компьютере (Error: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect)

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-studio

При попытке сгенерировать подписанный APK-файл в Android Studio на другом компьютере (не на том, на котором генерировала ключ), возникает ошибка:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42301Library UP-TO-DATE
......
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:packageRelease FAILED
```

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
>   Failed to read key SkidkaRu from store "C:\Users\elena\keyappskidkaru.jks": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Пароль точно правильный ввожу. Ключ скопировала с компа, на котором его сгенерировала впервые, и прописала к нему путь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогло копирование ключа с помощью библиотеки AndroidKeystoreBrute с тем же паролем и key alias. Возможно старый ключ повредился каким-то образом, потому что при указании пути к нему alias вообще не обнаруживался.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего папка с ограничениями для данного пользователя. Попробуйте в корень, создать новый ключ, с новым паролем.

Comment: Новый ключ - не вариант, приложение уже выложено в маркете

Comment: Переместите его в другую папку